# Are there proxies like Tor2Web but not just for http connections?

Tags: onion-services, proxy, clear-net

Tor2Web allows access to Hidden services from clearnet. However I would like to know if there some other gateways which will allow connections to hidden services on custom port and allows different communication protocols from clearnet?

Answer (score 2):

You could configure a tor relay and so set up the `SocksPort` with your external IP and a port. But in this way, who intercept the connection will be able to see which HS are you trying to connect to. Plus this is unauthenticated and unencrypted (this is the worst part) more info [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SocksPort).

Keep in mind that in this case your relay will be seen as an open proxy, I don't know what someone's abuse could cause to you. I mean that you could be responsible for illicit activity (but I repeat, these are just suppositions).

Comment: I was looking for some already established free service like tor2web.com

Comment: I don't think that there is one for what I explained above. I mean, why should one use a service that is totally not secure? And so, why create a service that is not secure that allow spying and manipulating of the data?

Comment: If I'm ssh'ing from a box on which tor is not available, and I've installed a hidden service on the target for the purpose of getting around a firewall, then this is a perfectly sensible thing to ask.